# Can't set Guzzle Content Type

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to request this way:

```
$body = [];
$body['holder_name'] = $full_name;
$body['bank_code'] = $bank_number;
$body['routing_number'] = $branch_number;
$body['account_number'] = $account_number;
$body['type'] = 'checking';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
'base_url' => [$url, []],
'headers'  => ['content-type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
    'defaults' => [
         'auth' => [$publishable_key, ''],
],
    'body' => json_encode($body),
]);
```

The problem is that this request is being set without Content-Type.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok .. the problem was that I was setting body and headers outside of defautls. the solution is:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
'base_url' => [$url, []],
'defaults' => [
     'auth' => [$publishable_key, ''],
     'headers'  => ['content-type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'],
     'body' => json_encode($body),
],
]);
```

Comment: Apparently  there is no "defaults" settings in GuzzleHTTP 6.2 anymore, every setting that's passed when creating the client becomes a default for this client instance.

Answer (score 14):

### Guzzle 6

> Guzzle will set the Content-Type header to
>   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when no Content-Type header is
>   already present.

You have 2 options.

<kbd>Option 1: On the Client directly</kbd>

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(
    ['headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ]
    ]
);
```

<kbd>Option 2: On a Per Request basis</kbd>

```
// Set various headers on a request
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$client->request('GET', '/whatever', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ]
]);
```

---

You can refer to [Guzzle 6: Request Options](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html)

Comment: another options is to use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface $request->withHeader($header, $value) . see [Guzzle Middleware doc](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html)

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same issue with the Hubspot API that requires to set `application/json` as Content-Type for POST requests.

**I fixed it this way**

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://api.hubapi.com/',
    'timeout'  => 5,
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
]);
```

**And then performing my requests the regular way**

```
try
{
    $response = $client->request('POST', '/contacts/v1/contact/email/test@test.com/profile',
    ['query' => MY_HUBSPOT_API_KEY, 'body' => $body]);
}
catch (RequestException $e) { print_r($e); }
```

I hope this helps.